# Spinner on fly. How do I identify each spinner?

Tags: android

I'm drawing some spinners on fly.
The question is, how I can to know that I'm using in onItemSelected.

Example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <5; i + +) {
        sp = new Spinner (this);
        sp.setAdapter (un_adapter);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener (this);
    }
```

What spinner I'm using?

```
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView <?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {
    //??????????????
    }
```

Comment: give it a tag, or keep its id somewhere, or keep a reference to it.

Comment: I thought, but how? I tried but got nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setTag and getTag to identify current spinner. i.e

```
 for (int i = 0; i <5; i + +) {
        sp = new Spinner (this);
        sp.setAdapter (un_adapter);
        sp.setTag(i.toString());
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener (this);
    }
```

and can get it like

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int p,
                long arg3) {
                            arg0.getTag;
                           }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do this.

Create a spinner, add an id to him.

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);
spinner.setId(R.id.defined);
```

and then add an id to the id.xml file in the Values folder.
like this:

```
<item name="defined_0" type="id"/>
<item name="defined_1" type="id"/>
```

for your purpose it will come in handy that the id represented by defined_0 + 1 is the same as the defined_1. So you can add the ids programmatically in your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <5; i + +) {
    sp = new Spinner (this);
    sp.setId(R.id.defined_0+i);
    sp.setAdapter (un_adapter);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener (this);
    }
```

If you put it like this,
the id defined_1 will be linked to the spinner number 2. =)

```
public void onItemSelected (AdapterView <?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {
    if (view.getID == R.id.defined_0){
       //whatever is supposed to happen if Spinner 1 is selected/used
    }
}
```